# Parsing XML trying to get next childnode

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to get the following data from an `XML file` in an Android app

```
<studentenhuizen version="1.0" timestamp="1399460687">
<studentenhuizen>
<adres>Aalbeeksesteenweg</adres>
<huisnr>19</huisnr>
<gemeente>KORTRIJK</gemeente>
<aantal_kamers>14</aantal_kamers>
</studentenhuizen>
</studentenhuizen>
```

Code to load XML file

```
int next = parser.next();
String name = null;
while (next != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
if (next == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
name = parser.getName();
if (name.equals("studentenhuizen")) {
//what do I have to here?

Studentenhuis st = new Studentenhuis(adres, huisnr,gemeente, aantalKamers);
huizen.addst
}
next = parser.next();
```

Note: I do get all the 199 results when I ask for `huizen.size();` but obviously they're empty as I don't know know how to get Adres, huisnr, ...

Comment: Well, before anything else, there you have a problem, because you have the same TAG name for two different elements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've changed the root now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (name.equals("studentenhuizen")) {
    next = parser.next();
     if (name.equals("adres")) {
          next = parser.next();
          String adres = parser.getText();
     }
    //Similarly for other fields
    Studentenhuis st = new Studentenhuis(adres, huisnr,gemeente, aantalKamers);
}
```

Comment: parser.getName(); will give me the node name "adres", any idea how I can get the value?

Comment: The result is empty then, even when I do ´next = parser.next();
if (name.equals("adres")){
Log.d("TEST", "It worked");
}`

Answer (score 1):

Well, then you can maybe add a new method, something like this:

```
private Studentenhuis parseStudentenhuis(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {

        //Declare this variables
        adres, huisnr,gemeente, aantalKamers;

    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }
        String name = parser.getName();

        if (name.equals("adres")) {
            adres = getText();
        } else if (name.equals("huisnr")) {
            huisnr= getText();
        } else if (name.equals("gemeente")) {
         ....
        }
    }

    return new Studentenhuis(adres, huisnr,gemeente, aantalKamers);
}
```